# Linq to XML get item with id in id collection

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Given the XML below how would I go about getting a list of employees who have a position in the coordinators.coordinator > position_ids?

```
<employee id="000001">
 <username>Bernard</username>
 <first_name>BERNARD</first_name>
 <last_name>FISHER</last_name>
 <business_phone>011111111111</business_phone>
 <cell_phone>011111111112</cell_phone>
 <hr_contact_name>PETER MANNING</hr_contact_name>
 <contract_description>Permanent</contract_description>
 <positions>
  <position id="00000002" isPrimary="1">
  <title>DEVELOPMENT MANAGER</title>
  <department id="DV001">DEVELOPMENT</department>
  <manager_position>00000002</manager_position>
  <coordinators>
   <coordinator position_id="00013662"/>
   <coordinator position_id="00014488"/>
   <coordinator position_id="00022675"/>
   <coordinator position_id="00024364"/>
  </coordinators>
  </position>
 </positions>
</employee>
<employee id="000002">
<!-- ... --->
</employee>
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
//GET EMPLOYEE WITH CORORDINATORS AND SUBORINATES WITH POSITION ID
var q = from c in d.Elements().Elements().Elements("positions").Elements("position") where  (string)(c.Attribute("id")) == "028782"
        select new
            {
                PositionID = c.Parent.Parent.Attribute("id")
                ,Username = c.Parent.Parent.Element("username").Value
                ,FirstName = c.Parent.Parent.Element("first_name").Value
                ,LastName = c.Parent.Parent.Element("last_name").Value                      
                ,ContractDecription = c.Parent.Parent.Element("contract_description").Value
                ,Title = c.Element("title").Value
                ,Coordinators = (from coordinator 
                                in d.Elements().Elements().Elements("positions").Elements("position") 
                                join p in c on coordinator.Attribute("id").Value equals p.Attribute("id").Value

                                select new
                                    {
                                        PositionID = coordinator.Attribute("id")
                                        ,Username = coordinator.Parent.Parent.Element("username").Value
                                        ,FirstName = coordinator.Parent.Parent.Element("first_name").Value
                                        ,LastName = coordinator.Parent.Parent.Element("last_name").Value                            
                                        ,ContractDecription = coordinator.Parent.Parent.Element("contract_description").Value
                                        ,thenode = coordinator
                                    })
                ,thenode = c
            };

q.Dump();
```

Comment: Can you clarify more on what you mean when you say "list of employees who have a position in the coordinators.coordinator > position_ids?"

I initially assumed you just wanted to return employees who are coordinators but the > position_id on the end threw me. can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry what I am looking for is an employee with a sub list of Coordinators. A Coordinator is an Employee with a matched positions.position.id if that makes sense?

Comment: You mean, you want to get a list of all employees where that employee is in any employee's coordinator list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
var coordinatorIds =
    d.Elements("employee")
     .Elements("positions")
     .Elements("coordinators")
     .Elements("coordinator")
     .Select(c => c.Attribute("position_id").Value)
     .Distinct()
     .ToArray();

var coordinators =
    from c in d.Elements("employee")
    join id in coordinatorIds on c.Attribute("id").Value equals id
    select c;
```